# Proving a theorem using another theorem

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I need help proving this **Theorem 1**: If (k, b) = 1 and k|ab, then k|a.

I was looking at another theorem which may help me prove the above, but it doesn't make much sense to me.

**Theorem 2:** If a and b are relatively prime to m, then (ab, m) = 1.

From what I can understand is a and b are not necessarily relatively prime to each other but they relatively prime to m when multiplied together and when separate. However, I don't know how to use this information to prove Theorem 1.

Looking at Theorem 1, b alone is relatively prime to k but since k divides into a, a cannot be relatively prime to k.

Comment: $(a, b)$ stands for $a \wedge b$ i.e. $\gcd(a, b)$ ?

Comment: It means GCF of a and b is 1.

Comment: Then I don't think your theorem 2 is useful for this. Are you asked to prove theorem 1 with theorem 2?

Comment: No, it just says to prove it. I thought they were related somehow.

Comment: Do you know Bachet-Bézout's theorem/identity ? ($\exists(u,v)\in\mathbb{Z}^2 \text{ s.t. } au+bv = (a, b)$ and/or $(a, b) = 1 \iff \exists(u,v)\in\mathbb{Z}^2 \text{ s.t. } au+bv = 1$)

Comment: I do not. We just started the course (2nd week of semester), so we haven't learned much. I don't even know what most of those symbols mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way to prove theorem 1 is using Bachet-Bézout's theorem. But as you don't know it, let me first explain it what it is :

Bachet-Bézout's theorem state that exists two integers (let's call them $u$ and $v$) such that :
$$a \cdot u + b \cdot v = (a, b)$$

A way to prove this is using induction. Let $a$ an integer:

Call $P_b: \text{"exists u and v s.t. } a \cdot u + b \cdot v = (a, b)\text{"}$

Clearly, $P_0$ is true because for any $a$, 
$$a\cdot 1 + 0 \cdot 0 = a = (a, 0)$$

Suppose p is true for any integer up to $b - 1$. Then, using euclidean division :

$$a=bq+r \implies (a, b) = (b, r)$$

And $r < b$, so using $P_r$, exists $u'$ and $v'$ such that :
$$b \cdot u' + r \cdot v' = (a, b)$$
$$\iff b \cdot u' + (a-bq)\cdot v' = (a, b)$$

Then take $u=v'$ and $v = u'-qv'$, so you have :
$$a \cdot u + b \cdot v = (a,b)$$

---

So now, to prove your "Theorem 1" (which is Gauss theorem), we just need to use Bachet-Bézout's theorem :
$$\text{ exists u and v such that : } k \cdot u + b \cdot v = (k, b) = 1$$
$$\implies  k \cdot a \cdot u + b \cdot a \cdot v = 1 \cdot a = a$$

But $k|k \implies k|k \cdot a \cdot u$ and $k|a \cdot b \implies k|b \cdot a\cdot v$ hence :
$$k|k \cdot a \cdot u+b \cdot a \cdot v=a$$

Comment: Thank you very much! Makes much more sense now.

Comment: By the way, $\exists$ stands for exists, and $\in\mathbb{Z}$ basically means it is an integer.

Comment: @yayu Note that you can eliminate the unnecessary Bezout coefficients $\,u,v\,$ by using the gcd *distributive law* $\,(ak,ab)= a(k,b),\,$ which makes the proof much more concise, e.g. in my answer. Using the basic gcd laws shortens many proofs, and helps to focus in on the essence of the matter.

Answer (score 1):

$k$ can only contain prime and prime powers from $ab$ (because $k|ab)$. But as $gcd(k,b)=1$, $k$ can only contain prime and prime powers from $a, \therefore k|a.$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\,\ k\mid ak,ab\, \Rightarrow\, k\mid (ak,ab)=a(\overbrace{k,b}^{\large =\,1}) = a$